# как в html сделать так, что бы тег <a> перекидывал в Мобильное приложение?

Tags: python, html, django, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Пишу сайт на django(python). Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на гиперссылку, клиента перекидывало в мобильно приложение банка и желательно сразу на перевод денег нужному пользователю(яндекс кассу и т.д. не предлагайте, в данный момент это не подходит)

Comment: при чем тут python и django?

Comment: Система быстрых платежей, ссылка перехватывается если есть приложения. Сбербанк не катит правда.)